# What does the phrase "smiling to beat the band" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does the phrase "smiling to beat the band" mean?

In Vera Farmiga's new film *Higher Ground*, a character describes her uneasiness with door-to-door religious solicitors in this way: "Really nice, but in a creepy way. Too nice. It's like they're smilin' to beat the band."

What does that phrase mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Beat the band](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/to+beat+the+band)* is an idiom for *to the greatest possible degree*.

> It's like they're smiling as big as can be.

It's another form of "to beat all", akin to "that beats everything".

From the American Heritage Dictionary in Dictionary.com:

> Idioms & Phrases
>   **to beat the band**
>
> Also, **to beat all**.  To the greatest possible degree. For example, *The baby was crying to beat the band*, or *The wind is blowing to beat the band , or *John is dressed up to beat all . This idiom uses *beat* in the sense of "surpass." The first term may, according to one theory, allude to a desire to arrive before the musicians who led a parade, so as to see the entire event. Another theory holds that it means "make more noise than (and thereby beat) a loud band." [Colloquial; late 1800s]

It has [another meaning](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/to+beat+the+band) as well, which is not used in your example:

> **to beat the band**
>   very briskly; very fast. *He's selling computers to beat the band since he started advertising. She worked to beat the band to get ready for this.*

Comment: Fascinating! Thanks for the thorough response, much appreciated!